# spring ws clientinterceptor example

Tags: spring-ws

I need to add a custom soap header to an out going soap message in a spring ws 2.0 client.

I am using a client interceptor as follows.....

```
public class MyWebServiceClientInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {

    private QName qname = new QName(WEB_SERVICE_NAMESPACE, SOAP_HEADER_PART);
    private String testText = "<userName>myUser</userName><role>everything</role>";

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext context) throws WebServiceClientException {
        SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) context.getRequest();
        SoapHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        SoapHeaderElement newHeader = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(qname);
        newHeader.setActorOrRole(MY_SOAP_ACTOR);
        newHeader.setText(testText);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have confirmed the interceptor is called, but the header doesn't seem to get added. Am I meant to be doing some sort of "commit" to apply the header to the message ????

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need to do some type of commit. I do more or less the same thing (although I call it from inside the sendAndRecieve method of WS Template:

```
            SoapMessage soapMessage = (SoapMessage) message;
        SoapHeader soapHeader = soapMessage.getSoapHeader();
        QName qname = QNameUtils.createQName(...,...);
        SoapHeaderElement element = soapHeader.addHeaderElement(qname);
        element.setText(text);
```

Have you tried turning on message logging to see what the message acutally looks likes when it is sent out?

You can do this by creating a log4j.properties and adding these lines:

```
#log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.sent=TRACE
#log4j.logger.org.springframework.ws.client.MessageTracing.received=TRACE
```